# React Bootstrap split button block prop not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, split-button

I want to make my SplitButton take entire width and height of its current row. 
I tried to use the `block` prop for the SplitButton, but without luck.

fiddle -->
https://jsfiddle.net/f9vdksnu/5/

Answer (score 0):

have you try `inline-block`? on parent container?

Comment: but on this second with class test button looks like button in one line text and dropdown. I think this fix your problem

Comment: I need this entire SplitButton component to fill its container, which in my case is the row. Can you please provide a fiddle?

Comment: try on css add 
#record-status-select {
  width: 100px;
}

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/8xcbw5jg/)

Comment: Didn't work, especially due to the fact that I don't want an obsolete width, I just want it to expand to the entire row.

Comment: So change 100px to 100%

Comment: Tried it, does not work as well. Did you manage to make the fiddle code work?